# IdentityServer 4 : connect/authorize/callback address not found behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: c#, nginx, .net-core, identityserver4, nginx-reverse-proxy

hi i am new in identityserver 4 and trying to deploy my test project on the server.
i have client ids and api project which are dockerized. after playing around with identity server 4 and nginx reverse proxy configuration finally every thing work properly except the redirect callback after login.

##### STORY :

in my reverse proxy i have 3 upstreams as follow :

1. Client APP which is accessible by url https ://xxx.com/ itself. and it is configured as

> ```
>    location / {
>                     proxy_pass http ://Client;
>                     proxy_buffering off;
>                     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>                     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
>                     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
>     
>                     fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
>                     fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
>     
>             }
> ```

i added the below code to pipe line to set the original url. without this i got invalid redirect uri (in configuration setup i set it with proper address but in error it shows it trying to redirect to https ://Client/signin-iodc)

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("xxx.com");
    
    await next();
});
```

2. Identity Server 4 that is accessible by base URL https ://xxx.com/identity and also i can get the configuration properly with proper addresses. it is configured as

> ```
> location /identity/ {
>                 proxy_pass http ://Identity/;
>
>                 proxy_buffering off;
>                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
>                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
>
>                 fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
>                 fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
>
>         }
> ```

same here added the below code to pipe line to set the original url for Identity server

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("xxx.com/identity/");
    
    await next();
});
```

without this in openid-configuration i had the wrong addresses like https ://identity/connect....

3. Api resource which is not the problem here and it accessible on url https ://xxx.com/api/....

---

###### UPSTREAMS:

```
upstream Client{
        zone Client 64k;
        server localhost:5001;
}



upstream Identity{

        zone Identity 64k;
        server localhost:9001;
}
```

---

##### Problem:

now with this config everything works. i redirect to login page with proper url

> https ://xxx.com/identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%......

but after login it should go for

> https ://xxx.com/identity/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=

but it redirects to

> https ://xxx.com/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=

which not valid and obviously i get page can’t be found.

if i add identity to the same url it works properly and go to the home page of client since i have cookies and authorized.

i dont know if i messed up something here by adding the middle-ware for origin url or i missed some configuration in nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was in my middleware pipeline. before i had defined the base url for my identity server as

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) => 
{ 
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https"; 
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("xxx.com/identity/");
    
    await next(); 
});
```

which was ok. i got the correct discovery configuration with correct urls and also redirect to correct url for login and span around identityserver without problem except the **connect/authorize** on redirect after login as i explained in the question.

i changed it as follow:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) => 
{ 
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https"; 
    ctx.Request.Host = new HostString("xxx.com");
    ctx.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/identity");
    await next(); 
});
```

and for now my problem solved. i wont mark this solution as answer since i dont have any idea if this is the standard solution and best practice.